# ¿ Cómo mandar un ArrayList de un fragment a otro en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

estoy haciendo un proyecto de un carro de compras y quiero pasar el ArrayList del carrito, a un fragment para poder mostrarlo

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Es complicado ayudarte sin el código que estás haciendo... pero lo que tienes que hacer es crear una instancia de tu fragmento, a continuación un bundle que es el que te permitirá almacenar tu ArrayList del carrito de compras

```
ArrayList<String> productos= new ArrayList<>();
productos.add("Producto 1");
productos.add("Producto 2");
productos.add("Producto n");

MyCustomFragment fragment = new MyCustomFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("productos", productos);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

De esta forma ya tienes el ArrayList en tu fragmento... para mostrarlo simplemente tendrías que recuperar el valor y tratarlo como desees(hay muchas formas en las que podrías mostrar estos valores)